# We ARE / WERE just done with our meal now?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

If finished our meal last minute, and my friend call me and ask us to come to have a meal with him, which of the following two is correct in this context?

> We **are** just done with our meal now, Thank you.

or

> We **were** just done with our meal now. Thank you.

Comment: It's simply the first one.  The sentence literally has "now" in it - you are referring to "now" absolutely.   (You would only - ***sort of*** - use the second sentence in the unusual case you were talking about "a sequence of events that happened say last year" ***but*** then you would not say "now", of course.)

Comment: Note that you usually - but not always -  say "... just now done with X ..." rather than "... just done with X now...".  But that does not affect what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have been invited to a meal, but you have just finished eating one.

I think a native English speaker would phrase it differently

> Thank you, but we have just finished eating.

Comment: Thank you, but anyway it was important to me to know the tense while using the word done. In which situations I have to use *done* or *'finished'*? (I really don't have idea,  and they always look to me equal)

Comment: @JudiciousAllure Personally, as a UK Native English speaker "finished" sounds more natural. "_Thank you, but we have just done eating._", to my ear, sounds more American usage. But both are in common use.

Answer (score -2):

Were, since you are no longer eating.

For 'are' you could phrase it

> We are finished with our meal just now. Thank you.

or, colloquially

> We just got done eating, but thanks anyway.

Comment: "Were, since you are no longer eating."  That's **completely, totally wrong**!